# Как повесить на блок ссылку, которая не перекроет работу ссылок и обработчиков на внутренних блоках?

Tags: javascript, события, мышь

Есть блок `div` внутри секции `link` в котором есть своя внутренняя *ссылка ya.ru* и обработчики событий на внутренних `span`. В свою очередь, на внешнем блоке также зашита в атрибуте своя ссылка на google.com.

Как сделать так, чтобы по всему блоку секции `link` работала своя ссылка, а по внутреннему блоку своя и выполнялись все обработчики?

Т.е. на блоке `div` должны отрабатывать обработчики `plus`, `minus` и ссылка с `ya.ru`, а на свободной области внешней секции `link`, куда не входит блок `div`, по клику должна отработать ссылка `google.com`.
На текущий момент при клике на внутреннем блоке всегда срабатывает внешняя ссылка, хочу это поправить, но `e.stopPropagation()` не отрабатывает так, как я этого ожидал изначально.

```js
var link = document.getElementById('link');
var div = document.getElementById('div');

link.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  datalink = this.getAttribute("data-link");
  if (typeof(datalink) != 'undefined' && datalink != null) {
    window.location.href = link;
  }
});

div.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e) {
  console.log("mouseenter");
  e.stopPropagation();
  if (link) {
    link.style.pointerEvents = "none";
  }
});
div.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e) {
  console.log("mouseleave");
  e.stopPropagation();
  if (link) {
    link.style.pointerEvents = "initial";
  }
});
document.getElementById('plus').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log("plus");
});
document.getElementById('minus').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log("minus");
});
```

```css
#link {
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#div {
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<section id="link" data-link="https://google.com/">
  <div id="div">
    <span id="plus">+</span>
    <span id="minus">-</span>
    <a href="https://ya.ru/">Link</a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: непонятно как работает сейчас и как именно должно работать

Comment: @Grundy отредактировал вопрос. Теперь стало понятнее?

Comment: да, так лучше. Решается использованием .stopPropagation в обработчике клика по `div`. Зачем нужны обработчики mouseenter/leave непонятно

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался! `mouseenter/leave` нужно для того, чтобы курсор мыши вернулся на исходную позицию стрелки, а не был указателем как на ссылку. Решил добавлением `this.style.pointerEvents = "auto";
    this.style.cursor = "auto";` на обработчик `mouseenter`